# i want only admin to route and users to restrict

Tags: reactjs, roles

i want only admin to route to admindashboard and user should be restricted from going to the url:localhost:3000/admindashboard.But when the users also type the same url the user moves to the url. I have tried like this, and it didnt't work. i am new to react and pls help. the code is as below:

```
if (isValid) {
      const isAuth = await loginRoute(login);
      const role = isAuth[1];
      if (isAuth[0]) {
        if (role === "user") {
          history.push("/myvehicles");
        }
        if (role === "admin") {
          history.push("/admindashboard");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: specify each user routes separately in some constants and then put those roles in the switch on the base of the user so you dont have to use if else at every route

Answer (score 2):

You have to validate the user role inside the route component or create some general validation mechanism.

```
export function Admindashboard(props) {
  if (props.role === "user") {
   history.push("/myvehicles");
  } else {
   render();
  }
}
```